# WebGL and Hardware acceleration problems

Tags: hardware, hardware-acceleration, webgl

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 and in Windows 7 on my ATI Mobility Radeon 4300 series graphics card WebGL and hardware acceleration worked perfectly fine. Now on Ubuntu 12.04 I have tried both the open-source drivers and the FGLRX drivers and it no longer works. Could somebody please help? I use Google Chrome 18

Answer (score 0):

Try launching Chrome using this command:

```
google-chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

Then [try webgl test](http://get.webgl.org/)--it worked for me.

Comment: I got this from webgl test after using that command http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/3900/ahemh.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it helped me. I have acceleration in 11.10 but on 12.10 i didnt, this solve my problem.
http://ubuntufixer.blogspot.com/2012/12/enable-3d-webgl-in-chrome-chromium.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.